# Using hammer.js map zoom but tap function

Tags: jquery, mobile

I am creating an interactive map and looking to use hammer.js for the multitouch function.
I was wondering if there was a way to potentially zoom in and around the map, when finding a particular place, tapping that area to find out more information.

Any advice or tips would be so helpful!